# Get claim from Context in cshtml

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, httpcontext

I'm creating an IDP with Identityserver 4. The server is up and running. But now I want to restrict on whom can create users. In my scenario, the admin logs in locally on the server and adds/removes/etc the users.

So in the layout file I'm trying to get the own defined claim called user_type to check if the logged in user is the admin. I'm trying to do this with this code:

```
@using IdentityServer4.Extensions
@{
    string name = null;
    string type_user = null;
    if (!true.Equals(ViewData["signed-out"]))
    {
        name = Context.User?.GetDisplayName();
        type_user = Context.User?.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Type == 
"type_user")?.Value;
    }
}
```

Startup class with configuration:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connectionString = secret;
    services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<UserContext>(o => o.UseNpgsql(connectionString));

    services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

    var identityServerDataDBConnectionString =
        secret;

    var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie();

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddSigningCredential(LoadCertificateFromStore())
        .AddJanssenUserStore()
        .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryConfig.GetClients())
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(InMemoryConfig.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(InMemoryConfig.GetApiResource())
        .AddOperationalStore((options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                builder.UseNpgsql(identityServerDataDBConnectionString,
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        }));
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, UserContext userContext,
    PersistedGrantDbContext persistedGrantDbContext)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    persistedGrantDbContext.Database.Migrate();

    userContext.Database.Migrate();

    userContext.EnsureSeedDataForContext();

    app.UseIdentityServer();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();


}
```

When logging in and inspecting the value of Context.user, I notice that there are claims in the user. But the type_user is lacking. I use the Quickstart GUI from IdentityServer4.

What I think I should do is declare a scope somehow. But I'm not sure on how to do this.

Anyone got an idea?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you have code where you are adding the claim 'type_user'?

Comment: Show the startup config code as well as client setup config code.

Comment: @Aeseir added the config. This is on one server so there is no seperate client config. I want to know how to get the user server when the user is logged in.